# $L$ is an elliptic operator?

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, laplacian, elliptic-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $L$ be an unbounded operator, such that
$$L = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} h^{i,j}(x) \, \partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j}.$$
If the matrix $h^{i,j}(x)$ is non-degenerate (or $ \det h^{i,j}(x) \neq 0$), is that we can say that $L$ is an elliptic operator ?
If yes, any reference. Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of an elliptic operator? And, please, don't use the symbol $\Delta$, which is the Laplace differential operator for most mathematicians. If you agree with Wikipedia, then the answer is trivial... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator

Comment: A linear operator $L$ is said Elliptic if  the matrix $A(x)=(a_{ij}(x))$ of its symbol  is positive.

Comment: The answer is no. Take $h^{ij} = (-1)^i \delta_{ij}$. Then  $L$  is not elliptic.

Comment: @ Hans Engler: Here ([Elliptic operator](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org//index.php?title=Elliptic_operator)), the ellipticity means that  its principal symbol $\sigma(x,\xi)$ is an invertible matrix for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\xi\in \mathbb R^n - \{0\}$. Then, if  $\det h^{i,j}(x)\neq 0$ (i.e.,  $\sigma(x,\xi)$ is an invertible matrix) as above, the operator $L$ is elliptic. Is it not ?

Comment: Those are two different conditions. There are certainly invertible matrices which are not positive.